# Why isnt greedy matching working in perl regex group

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to grab only whats BETWEEN the body tags in html with perl regex (so don't want to include the actual body tags, thus using the groups to throw away the tags to variables).
Here are some short test subjects:

```
<body>test1</body>
<body style="bob">test2</body>
```

So first, simple version I tried was:

```
(?<=<body>).*(?=</body>)
```

which returns test 1 and empty string
So then I tried:

```
(?<=<body).*(?=</body>)
```

Which now gives a result for both tests, but of course has garbage: ">test1" and " style="bob">test2"

I've tried every variation of greedy match now in the first version, e.g.:`(?<=<body.*>).*(?=</body>)`
But it simply will not work! Any time I put the * in there I get errors. Anybody able to help out?

Comment: *"`(?<=<body>).*(?=</body>)` returns test 1 and empty string"*  What do you mean here? A regex pattern doesn't "return" anything at all, and this one doesn't even capture any substrings.

Comment: Are you saying that your data has multiple `<body>` tags?

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to grab only whats BETWEEN the body tags

In that case:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    if ($line =~ m{ <body [^>]*> (.+) </body> }xs) {
        print "[$1]\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
<body>test1</body>
<body style="bob">test2</body>
<!-- <body class="one"> --><body>This is why you should use an HTML parser</body>
```

Output:

```
[test1]
[test2]
[ --><body>This is why you should use an HTML parser]
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a shot. I am using a parser for pre-processing and some other stuff. Beautifulsoup in python. That portion is already stripping comments, script tags, etc, so by the time it gets to the perl for this task it should be very clean.

Comment: @mongoose: If you have your document in Beautiful Soup then it makes far more sense to extract the `<body>` element at that point once the HTML has been parsed. BS has no equivalent to the DOM `innerHTML`, but you can use `str(bsoup.body)` to get the text of the `<body>` element *including* the tags, and use Python or Perl to remove them. That makes much more sense than stringifying the BS object to turn it back into HTML, passing that to Perl, and parsing it again there.

Comment: After this matches `<body style="b>ob">test2</body>`, capture group 1 contains `ob">test2` and won't match `<body style="b>ob">test2</body >` at all.

Comment: @sln *That is why one should use an HTML parser*.

Comment: I totally agree, but that won't stop people from using regex. To be sure, the _tags_ themselves are described using regex and can safely be parsed as the first level text parsing. Nesting and other entity substitution are not in the regex realm. I have the defacto regex standard for parsing all tags, didn't post it here, only a partial.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for

```
while ($html =~ / <body[^>]*> ( (?: (?! </body\b ). )* ) /sxg) {
   say $1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think using `$&` is efficient. Personally, I'd use capture groups
but this works pretty good.

`/<(body)(?:\s+(?>"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|(?:(?!\/>)[^>])?)+)?\s*>\K[\S\s]*?(?=<\/\1\s*>)/`

https://regex101.com/r/EkPkLb/1

Expanded

```
 <
 ( body )                      # (1)
 (?:
      \s+ 
      (?>
           " [\S\s]*? "
        |  ' [\S\s]*? '
        |  (?:
                (?! /> )
                [^>] 
           )?
      )+
 )?
 \s* >
 \K 
 [\S\s]*? 
 (?= </ \1 \s* > )
```

*Note that to really find a particular tag, you have to consume all the

previous tags via a `(*SKIP)(?!)`, else your tag could be embedded inside

script literals, comments or invisible content.*

I wouldn't worry too much about it.
If you're interested I could post a fairly large proper regex,
but I doubt you'd be interested.

Answer (score -1):

Choosing the best pattern for your data depends on what kind of characters will be contained in your body tags.  An additional consideration is whether you want to aim for efficiency or minimal memory.

These are some suitable (or not) patterns for your case:

> 93steps    `~<body[^>]*>\K.*(?=</body>)~` #no capture group,no newline matches
>   105steps    `~<body[^>]*>\K[\S\s]*?(?=</body>)~` #no capture group, newline matches
>  
>   87steps     `~<body[^>]*>(.*)</body>~`  #capture group, no newline matches
>   96steps     `~<body[^>]*>([\S\s]*?)</body>~` #capture group, newline matches

Here is a [Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6vei8K/1) with three samples to show the impact of newline characters in your body text.